# How to add a specific input to the front a specific list item in Python

Tags: python

I wanted to my program display a list and ask the user what list item they completed. After they input that which will be an item in the list, it should insert an "X " in front of it. E.g if the list is [homework, chores] the list should then become [X homework, chores] if the user inputs "homework".

```
    run = True
    while run:
        input000 = input("Which items do you wish to record as done?")
    # Something the adds X to the front of the chosen list item (from the input)
```

Comment: what you tried to do and what is your code / problem?

Answer (score 2):

```
list_item = ["homework", "chores"]
while True:
    input000 = input("enter something")
    for i in range(len(list_item)):
        if input000 == list_item[i]:
            list_item[i] = f"X {list_item[i]}"
```

Answer (score 1):

A more Pythonic approach is to use the list's *index()* method in conjunction with an exception handler to validate the user's input.

You'll also need some way to break out of the loop - perhaps when all items in the list have been marked as "done"

Something like this:

```
todo_list = ['homework', 'chores']

def todo():
    for e in todo_list:
        if e[0] != 'X':
            yield e

while sum(1 for _ in todo()) > 0:
    print(*todo(), sep='\n')
    item = input('Choose something: ')
    try:
        i = todo_list.index(item)
        todo_list[i] = f'X {item}'
    except ValueError:
        print("\aThat's not in the list")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can search for your object then adjust it:

```
for item in list_item:
    if item == input000:
        item = 'X ' + item
```

Please, for the future, include your own attempts.